# What is the concept of entities which cannot have a chart?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

When creating dashboards inside Dynamics CRM, we're getting the below error:

[image: There are no charts for this entity]

> There are no charts for this entity. Click on the Help button to get more information on creating charts.

How do we decide which entities **cannot** have a chart? What is the concept here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is self-explanatory: You have not created any charts for the DocProject entity.

Comment: That's what we're doing. We're trying to create charts for the entity in concern but it's not allowing to do so

Comment: Then I would suggest creating a question with the issues you experience when creating a chart.

Comment: Okey, [this is what we need here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40377089/2404470)

Comment: You just copy/pasted the contents of this question to a new question...

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
_"It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is"_